# PDFs that worked a couple of weeks ago now fail with CloudPrint

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-print

I have a test PDF file that worked since the start of the year, but no longer prints in the last two weeks. The PDF has not changed.

The job is successfully sent to the printer, but only a line feed comes out.

This is occurring both through my own code, and through the Cloud Print Management interface when uploaded.

The PDF can be downloaded from https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_JoJgZoLj2rZ0FmR3dZSGhjUUk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The same document printed via Cloud Print in Chrome works, but not through the Cloud Print Management UI at https://www.google.com/cloudprint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why this was downvoted, but the issue ended up being that Microsoft Report Services 2008 creates slightly out-of-spec PDFs. The issue was resolved by upgrading Report Services which fixed the out-of-spec PDF issue.

It's still unclear why the the Cloud Print API was accepting the PDFs initially, and then suddenly stopped printing the same PDFs (this was a production environment, so there weren't changes on our side). I can only assume Google updated the service at their end.